# R fit gamma distributions using fitdist gives warnings and is different from fitdistr

Tags: r, distribution, gamma-distribution, gamma-function

I am using `fitdist ()` from `fitdistrplus` package to fit gamma distributions. Most of the data are fitted fine, but I get a warning for one group of data like below. It seems to be related to `NaN` produced in `Std. Error`. Also, I found different results produced using `fitdistr` from `MASS`.

```
fit.gamma = fitdist(data, 'gamma')

Warning messages:
1: In sqrt(diag(varcovar)) : NaNs produced
2: In sqrt(1/diag(V)) : NaNs produced
3: In cov2cor(varcovar) :
  diag(.) had 0 or NA entries; non-finite result is doubtful

#estimates
> fit.gamma
Fitting of the distribution ' gamma ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
         estimate Std. Error
shape    818.3582        NaN
rate  528503.7582        NaN

#different results produced using fitdistr from MASS
      shape         rate    
     820.7819   530073.2864 
 (   121.4543) ( 78460.8728)
```

The sample data from `dput()` is

```
c(0.00163517802885779, 0.00160283775056125, 0.00148355878584797, 0.00156397046432363, 
0.00162024854828131, 0.00156768768420791, 0.00158063023100016, 0.00156508718537038, 
0.00158003450240634, 0.00153358763566883, 0.00161065493852838, 0.00149028640335203, 
0.00162802968564173, 0.00156671606699238, 0.00154716199638081, 0.00153821195940563, 
0.00162198744285207, 0.00164083522311704, 0.00160865087968146, 0.00144217049528351, 
0.00153505545581709, 0.00151854732860282, 0.00157043155113409, 0.00162826610639283, 
0.00148190133362775, 0.00159462274874306, 0.00156724510802065, 0.0015398433747737, 
0.00143860062975494, 0.00150409532005301, 0.00153848336893089, 0.00151664158431484, 
0.00158084694063614, 0.00154878376860822, 0.00144337583756375, 0.00154777476470974, 
0.00160737367968485, 0.00149589176429248, 0.00151175669790827, 0.00152465054164807, 
0.00144735761146658, 0.0015726344621995, 0.00155360393089093, 0.00156793539059828, 
0.00162794136974673, 0.00158943155328826, 0.0016170212947375, 0.00162497885156522, 
0.00148874480354704, 0.00153209305693994, 0.00152311018565133, 0.00151099524254965, 
0.00157917892375966, 0.00154874669553882, 0.00154939184680954, 0.00153031019277051, 
0.00162243261815283, 0.00157590294470343, 0.00148554642291284, 0.00153540799890674, 
0.00154243522592646, 0.00160275040086466, 0.00157940839557194, 0.00156961922875331, 
0.00155304074589656, 0.00152928212568257, 0.00159290538926061, 0.00155801215578425, 
0.00155369439113824, 0.00145084623308752, 0.00155089000592941, 0.00155886786525376, 
0.00148652203536432, 0.0015927863907019, 0.00151196015173343, 0.0015821024463818, 
0.00160081599038558, 0.00156313209340047, 0.00163608907687576, 0.00153841239422154, 
0.0014710592012673, 0.00159246516016538, 0.00152258152415454, 0.00162132418508525, 
0.00140478594523462, 0.00151683262604363, 0.0016052558226825, 0.00147646957382916, 
0.0015132984105642, 0.00146861128575331, 0.00153106862171981, 0.00155880526046832, 
0.001550953370886, 0.00158975519781942, 0.00142012723811699, 0.00155218402168674, 
0.00156750756220327, 0.0015045948435867, 0.00159416372305572, 0.0014232058948302)
```

Also, here are the plots for the fitted gamma distribution.

[image]

**I wonder what the warning actually means and why the results are different from those produced using `fitdistr`.**

Comment: If you play around with the initial estimates, like: `fitdist(data, 'gamma', start= list(shape=800, rate=528503) )` one can avoid the warning and calculate the standard error.

Comment: Try scale your data e.g. `fit = fitdist(data*1000, 'gamma')` same (yet scaled) estimates, no warnigns and s.e.'s [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230420/alternatives-to-fitdistr-for-gamma-in-r)

Comment: @Dave2e Thanks for the suggestion. May I know what does `start` do? Particularly, would it affect the reliability of the stats?

Comment: @user20650 Brilliant! It works like a charm. Is it because the original values (decimals) are too small to be handled by further operations?

Comment: sometimes optimisers need a little help but specifically as oyu are fitting with mle, would seem to be s similar issue as given in [comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230420/alternatives-to-fitdistr-for-gamma-in-r#comment436547_230470) from same ink above.

Comment: The "start" option provides the initial estimates for the fitted parameters.  Sometimes the default initial estimates are too far off lead to errors such as a failure to convergence or illegal operations.

Comment: @user20650 I see. The estimates are nearly the same (only decimals are different; rate is now 1/1000 of the unscaled one). Also, it now produced values for `Std. Error` which was previous NaN. If I understand correctly, by default `fitdist` compute `hessian` but failed as "two parameter estimates differ by several orders of magnitude", whereas by default `fitdistr` does not compute hessian and therefore omits the potential issue and produce different (less precise) results?